# Beamer: Inconsistent formatting of enumerate subitems?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to change the formatting of enumerate items and subitems. Unfortunately I'm not getting consistent behavior when nesting an enumerate list within an itemize list -- all other combinations are fine

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{green}\textbullet}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{red}\textbullet}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\color{green}\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\color{red}\insertsubenumlabel.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Pure lists are fine:

\begin{itemize}
\item text
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Mixed lists are bad \emph{only} for enumerate:

\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `beamer` increments the counter `\@itemdepth` (which controls the level of nesting of `itemize` environments) at the beginning of `enumerate` environments, but not the counter `\@enumdepth` (which controls the level of nesting of `enumerate` environments) at the beginning of `itemize` environments.

This patch adds the missing increment to `itemize` environments to produce the desired output. Add it somewhere to your preamble (i. e. between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\itemize\endcsname{\advance\@itemdepth\@ne}{\advance\@itemdepth\@ne\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]